# How can I place a footnote at the bottom right margin of the page?

Tags: footnotes

How can I place a footnote at the bottom right margin of the page?

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{red}{\arabic{footnote}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn
    \textcolor{red}{My footnote symbol} \footnote{\textcolor{red}{I want this footnote at the extreme bottom right margin of this document (just inside the margins, but at the bottom right corner of this page)}}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\footnotelayout{m}`?

Comment: Thanks @Tom...! But, how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution of @oliversm to the problem of @Thev, described in
[Clash between paracol and footmisc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541659/clash-between-paracol-and-footmisc):

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{paracol}

% Solution to my problem _______________
\footnotelayout{m} 
\usepackage[bottom, flushmargin]{footmisc} 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{
    \setlength\parindent{1em}
    \noindent
    \mbox{\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}\,}{#1}}
\makeatother
% Solution to my problem _______________

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{red}{\arabic{footnote}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn
    \textcolor{red}{My footnote symbol} \footnote{\textcolor{red}{I want this footnote at the extreme bottom right margin of this document (just inside the margins, but at the bottom right corner of this page)}}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]